# How to implement FAB without support library in API >= 21

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

This might be a very silly or basic question.  I am new to android development and am using Support Library to implement FAB search button, using "android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton" component. Now I was wondering if I need use a separate layout for API 21 or greater and implement the same button without support library component? If so which component should I use, I couldn't anything equivalent to FloatingActionButton.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No there isnt. You have to use android design support.

Comment: There is no FAB implementation in the core Android SDK, if that's what you mean. Your choices are to use the Android Design Support library's implementation, use a third-party implementation, or roll your own from scratch. I would recommend either of the first two.

Comment: Why should you use a third party library instead of the official library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's your approach, but if you need a good FAB I can recommend this library [Clans/FloatingActionButton](http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1684) This library requires Android API Level 14+; its easy to use and you no need to worry about Google FAB design or Lollipop target and include goods animations and very fast implementations.

Why this library?

- Easy to implement
- Good animations
- The last update is today (June 21, 2015), so really have persons working hard for better this library
- It works on android API 14 onwards, (ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH, JELLY_BEAN, KITKAT, LOLLIPOP, Android M... etc etc)
- You don't know how to use it? no problem, look the easy implementation tutorial here: [Github](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) or here: [android-arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1684) (They are the same)
- But the main reason I recommend this library is because it is now that I'm using on a project I'm developing, I've tried others, but I honestly believe this is the best (at least for now)

In some cases Google does not care much for the developers and said it was easy overwrite a FameLayout view and create your own FAB button, but often developers do not have time to take the trouble to cast a view to a button.

Strongly I hope this is helpful to you

PD: I don't know to speak in english very well, so apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android design support provided FAB from Android 2.1 and above by using the android design library. 
To add the library just add the below in build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

You need not have separate layout for API>=21, the same FAB works for all the versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, `design` depends on `support-compat`.